# operations on a variable from a data.frame with time points

Tags: r, time, dataframe

I am stuck in a problem and send you a call for help (i went through similar questions but could not find exactly what i need, although it seems simple) : 
i have an original dataframe from 50 patients with 3 time points (reproducible code below) and a variable of interest called "Ht". My goal is to study the variations of Ht between these 3 time points, for example according to another variable (ex here the numerical variable "A").

```
    id  <-  rep(c(seq(1,50,1)),3)
    time  <- factor(rep(c("day1", "day2", "day3"), c(50,50,50)), levels=c("day1", "day2", "day3"), labels=c("day1", "day2", "day3"), ordered=TRUE)
    Ht  <- rnorm(150, mean=30, sd=3)
    A  <- rnorm(150, mean=7, sd=10)
    dfrm  <-  cbind (id,time,Ht,A)

    > head(dfrm)
      id time       Ht          A
 [1,]  1    1 28.64048 11.1595852
 [2,]  2    1 28.30068  4.2925773
 [3,]  3    1 32.51943 21.2013316
 [4,]  4    1 30.66561  0.6980816
 [5,]  5    1 28.92749 22.2756818
 [6,]  6    1 33.82217 14.2877789
```

I would like to study the differences between Ht values between day 1 and day2, as well as between day 2 and day 3, as well as between day 1 and day 3. But i would like to insert those calcultations form indidual data together with ID values, and other variables. 
I do not know if it is better to build a new data.frame, but i guess yes. 
Could someone suggest a simple way to proceed?
Thank you very much in advance.
Denis

Comment: i don't know if this was clear... but for example if i create this value for each individuals : diff12 <- dfrm$Htp[dfrm$time=="1"]-dfrm$Htp[dfrm$time=="2"], how could i include it in a data.frame together with "id" and variable "A"? Thank you !

Comment: Ok, for a given id you'll have `Ht` diffs but what about `A` (which also depends on time for a given id)?

Comment: In a new data.frame, i thought (but that's a guess) that the variable 'A' could be splitted into 3 columns (3 variables) 'A1', 'A2', and 'A3'. Part of my question is about programming, but it is also about "how to organize data" in such a case... Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jack! I tried but the code you proposed doesnt seem to work for me.. In fact, what i would like is to be able to plot the differences between Ht at the 3 time points, depending on individual A values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 library(plyr)
 dfrm <- data.frame(dfrm)
 out <- ddply(dfrm, .(id), function(x) {
        x <- x[order(x$time),]
        x$diff <- c(NA, diff(x$Ht))
        x$diff2 <- c(NA, NA, diff(x$Ht, 2))
        x
    })
```

Comment: Thank you Jack, but in fact, what i get is the following error message after i enter your function : "Erreur dans eval.quoted(.variables, data) : 
  envir must be either NULL, a list, or an environment."  Don't you ?

Comment: Now it works ! (with the additional code 'dfrm <- data.frame(dfrm)'. Thanks! My problem is that i don't understand everything from your code (any simple ddply reference guide?).

Comment: I think i understand it more/less... But what's the meaning of the "2" at the end of the definition of diff2? Thanks anyway !! ++++

Comment: @den `ddply` is one of the `plyr` functions so any documentation on `plyr` is good. Here's some top hits from google that look good: http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/workshops/r-intro/lectures/6-advancedmanipulation.pdf, the actual paper http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01, official documentation http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/plyr.pdf. The functions in `plyr` are very similar to the base `apply` functions (`apply`, `sapply`, `tapply`, etc.). Look at `?diff` to see what the 2 does. It takes a 2 lag difference.